# so: A terminal interface for Stack Overflow

Tags: app, stackoverflow

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: demo gif]

### About

This is a simple terminal interface to the Stack Exchange network. I created it as an exercise in learning Rust but also because I think it could be useful. It's for anyone who has quick questions that they want answered from within the terminal. (Probably not very well suited to hard research questions that would require bouncing around multiple sites; the browser is better suited to such tasks.)

It works by searching for question IDs relevant to a user-supplied query (either via the Stack Exchange search/advanced endpoint, or optionally via Google or DuckDuckGo), then fetching the question & answer data from the Stack Exchange API. Some light markdown rendering is done to make the terminal UI a bit more pleasant. One unique aspect of the application is that you can search multiple StackExchange sites at the same time.

#### License

Open source, licensed under MIT.

#### Download

View installation instructions [here](https://github.com/samtay/so#installation).

#### Platform

It's built with Rust and is very portable. If you're willing to install from source, I think you'll have trouble finding somewhere where it *doesn't* run.

### Contact

You can open up GitHub issues if you encounter problems with the application.

### Code

I wrote this in Rust, and the main framework involved for the TUI is [cursive](https://github.com/gyscos/Cursive), but all of the dependencies deserve credit for its existence. You can view the code and make contributions on GitHub, but please read the [contributing guidelines](https://github.com/samtay/so/blob/master/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md) first.

Comment: Super Impressive!